# config hadoop files (one node cluster)

Tags: hadoop

In the newest hadoop versions like 2.7 what are the appropriate and necessary configurations?

I'm reading some documentation to try install hadoop just in one node using a virtual machine  but I'm not sure that I'm doing this correctly.

I'm configuring core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</vaue>
</property>
</configuration>
```

And hdfs-site.xml

```
  <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

Theese are the unique configuration files needed in newest versions and they are ok?

And also, mapred-site.xml to configure job tracker is necessary in the newest versions?

When I start the cluster it starts but the secondary namenode appears with 0.0.0.0 it is normal?

0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/logs/hadoop-hadoopadmin-secondarynamenode-hadoop.out

Comment: If you download the Cloudera quickstart VM, everything is configured for you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be ok. You can check [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) for all the configurations needed to set up a Single Node Cluster.

Comment: Thanks! And the mapred-site.xml is necessary to configure in the newest versions?